# when i build the motor-blog with mongodb and tornado, it doesn't work

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado

the motor-blog's source code is here
https://github.com/ajdavis/motor-blog
when i visit the 127.0.0.1:8888
there is a problem

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado-3.2.dev1-py2.7.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1134, in _execute
    self._when_complete(self.prepare(), self._execute_method)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado-3.2.dev1-py2.7.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1693, in prepare
    raise HTTPError(self._status_code)
HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found
```

my systerm is osx 10.8 ,python version is 2.7.5

Comment: Have you tried 127.0.0.1:8888/blog ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to point your browser to 127.0.0.1:8888/blog like @Nisan.H says